# how to export java applet

Tags: java, ftp, applet, noclassdeffounderror

First of all I'm not a Java programmer, so maybe (hopefully :D) this problem could be very simple to solve.
I've wrote a simple applet to send file from client to a remote FTP server with a third-part library. When I run it in my eclipse applet viewer everything works correctly, but when i try it in my web browser I see a message like this:

```
Exception in thread "thread applet-prova.class-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/FileTransferClient
    at prova.start(prova.java:32)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I suppose there is some compiling/packaging issue... the applet should be well signed so, no security problem should be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` means that `com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/FileTransferClient` was there at compile time but is  missing at runtime.

I'm not really an Applet expert but as far as I know, you need to list all dependencies (i.e. including the jar providing the above class) in the `archive` attribute of the `<APPLET>` tag.

If you are using `<OBJECT>` or `<EMBED>`, see **Q: How do I specify a JAR file as part of an OBJECT or EMBED tag?** in the [FAQ](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/faq/developer.html).

Actually, providing the HTML might help here.

Comment: the html look like this:

<applet width="300" height="300"  classpath="bin" code="prova.class" archive="invio.jar"> </applet>

the library I use in the file should be inside the jar, altought i'm not sure I've packed it correctly...

Comment: @ArtoAle: Is the library unpacked inside the jar? If it isn't, I don't think it's going to work. Can you run `jar xvf invio.jar` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: of course, here it comes:

decompresso: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
decompresso: META-INF/SIGNAPPL.SF
decompresso: META-INF/SIGNAPPL.DSA
     creato: META-INF/
decompresso: prova.class
decompresso: edtftpj.jar
     creato: com/
     creato: com/enterprisedt/
     creato: com/enterprisedt/net/
     creato: com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/
     creato: com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/internal/
     creato: com/enterprisedt/net/ftp/test/
     creato: com/enterprisedt/util/
     creato: com/enterprisedt/util/debug/
     creato: com/enterprisedt/util/proxy/

dunno how to format more human-readeble way